# How to restore EFI in MacBook Pro Retina 13"?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, firmware

I've stopped an update of OS X in the middle! Now all I have when I boot the system is the normal beep sound of `POST` for hardware check.

I've [found a link](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1830?locale=en_US) that's been mentioned Apple has released a flash version of firmware update but for mid-2015 macbook 15 inches.

Now I'm stuck I don't have access to anything! I have access to an iMac in case needed.

Could someone lead me to a right direction? How should I restore the firmware?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the chat we had, where I was able to get more details like:

- You wiped out all partitions on the HDD
- You were getting the -2002F error during Internet Recovery

(Both of these are key pieces of info to put into the original question, by the way. )

[image: -2002F error message]

Your only option is to reinstall OS X from boot media.  You can either take it into an Apple Store and have them reinstall or have someone you know has a Mac download OS X and create a bootable USB for you.  [See the answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228297/new-ssd-problem/228301#228301) - different question, but the answer is still the same:  reinstall OS X from scratch via boot media.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36166/discussion-between-alireza-hos-and-allan).