# How to make SSD Drive bootable from a disk utilies restore

Tags: backup, time-machine, sata

My mid-2009 mac book pro hard drive is dying so I bought an SSD to replace it.  I tried plugging in the ssd drive to the mac via a usb to sata connection and using SuperDuper to copy the contents (saw a video and it looked easy), but it took forever and I got a generic input output error.  Next I tried restoring from a time machine backup to the ssd drive.  picture an external hard drive with the time machine backup connected to my mac book via usb and my ssd drive connected to the mac book pro via usb. I went into Apple Disk Utilities and did a restore from the external hard drive to the ssd drive.  It took about 16 hours, but it completed.  So now I have 2 drives with the same information - at least I think.  I wanted the ssd drive to be bootable, but it's not.  Can someone explain what a restore really does and how I can make the ssd drive bootable so that I can replace the dying, old mac book hd.  Note: I want to make the ssd drive internal and not keep it as a bootable external drive.  Thanks!

Comment: why not just install the SSD into the MacBook Pro rather than run it from USB; which is going to be s-l-o-w as it's only USB 2.0? You said you have TM backup....

Comment: SSD wasn't bootable. it was a raw drive with nothing on it.  that's my question...how do I get that ssd drive bootable. I thought the restore would do that

Comment: Also, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228297/new-ssd-problem/228301#228301

Comment: Thank you, those look relevant....I'll try and report back.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Ask Different. Why don't you install the SSD into your computer, boot into macOS Recovery and restore from a Time Machine backup? That is in my experience bulletproof (have done it a couple of times), see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904 for details.

Comment: Thanks, for the info.  I tried booting into MacOS Recovery, but I get a nasty error - panic (cpu 1 caller long memory address): "Process 1 exec of /sbin/launched failed, errno 5~@/Library/Caches...... I should have added that data point into my initial summary. I am working on creating an external USB bootable drive and going from there.

Answer (score -1):

Steps I followed to solve:
Downloaded El Capitan to Ssd drive
Removed old drive replaced with SSD drive 
Ran migration utility from time machine backup
Rebooted and working great. Thanks for the help!