# trying to revive a mac pro 1.1 without a disk drive or preinstalled software

Tags: mac-pro

I have a mac pro 1.1 which came without any DVD drives or HDDs, I put an SSD into one of the slots and want to install any working OS.

it however cannot get into any boot menu, it boots normally with the chime but doesn't display anything on screen.

Video card is the original nvidia 7300, RAM is original. Debug lights show video card present, EFI goes on for a split second during boot but goes off after.

What steps can I take to turn this into a working machine?

Comment: See this post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228297/new-ssd-problem/228301#228301

Comment: I don't believe USB booting is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a ghost image (a duplicate of the drive of another mac pro) I managed to get it functioning correctly without the need for a DVD / CD reader.